# Locust load testing - Change hatch rate from 1 second to say 20 seconds? (1 locust every 20 seconds)

Tags: python, python-3.x, load-testing, locust

I'm doing some load testing with locust and I cant seem to figure out how to change the Hatch Rate to a slower ramp up rate.  **1 locust per second** is still too fast so is there a way to change this to something that would resemble **1 locust every 20 seconds**?

I've tried using `gevent.sleep(19)` within the on_start method and setting the hatch rate to **1 locust per second** in the UI but **this only hatches each locust 1 second apart** and then each hatched locust sleeps for 19 seconds (they are still 1 seconds apart).

Is there a way of forcing each locust hatched at run time to wait 20 seconds before the next locust executes? (e.g. the first locust hatches and runs the on_start method, the next locust waits 19 seconds and then runs the on_start method, the next locust waits 19 seconds more and then runs the on_start method.)

Answer (score 4):

The hatch rate/ramp up parameter accepts float values. Use a hatch rate of 0.05 to spawn one user every 20 seconds.

Comment: Yes, thank you @Cyberwiz this dramatically slows down the ramp rate to about 1 locust every 30 seconds.  What if you had 2 User classes within your test file and you only wanted one of the User classes to have this ramp rate?  Could the ramp rate be handled/controlled via the test file?

Comment: Yes, you can control the hatch rate in code. That's possible via Load Shapes. https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/generating-custom-load-shape.html

However, if you have two different user classes you may not want to use them together unless you can use `weight` to define an acceptable set ratio between them (e.g. 2 user1 for every 8 user2). If weights don't work for you, you'd need separate Locust files.

Comment: This can now be achieved using `fixed_count` https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.User.fixed_count